# URDF - XML Scheme as XSD

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Community,
since URDF is XML based,
I wonder whether there is an existing XML scheme,
which I could use in order to marshal/unmarshal appropriate objects.

It would be great, if there is one!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9835/urdf---xml-scheme-as-xsd/) by [Byron](https://answers.ros.org/users/477/byron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went looking for it for awhile, but it doesn't seem too high on the Willow priority queue.
[relevant ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4328)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0